# how to create a set of users with the same prefix in mysql? Using wildcard?

Tags: mysql

I understand that mysql allows to use wildcard % to match hostnames with the same prefix. For example, `user@'abc.%'`

However, I wonder can I use wildcard % in username to match all users with the same prefix.
For example, 
`create USER 'user%'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
I tried this command, but it seems that it will only match username 'user%' instead of matching all usernames with prefix 'user'.

Can anyone confirm this, and is there any way I can create a set of users with the same prefix? Thanks!

Comment: Users aren't "matched" - their accounts are explicitly created. So `'user%'` would have to create a (theoretically) infinite amount of users to satisfy your needs. Usernames could theoretically be implemented to be patterns just like host names, but I know no system that does it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/account-names.html) defines how you can specify account names.
The host name can contain wildcards, but the user name not:

> A user name is either a nonblank value that literally matches the user
>   name for incoming connection attempts, or a blank value (empty string)
>   that matches any user name.

Besides that wildcards only make sense when you want to match existing accounts.
If something like this would be valid:

```
CREATE USER 'user%'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

then what should be the user names of the created accounts?